# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no Element

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am tying to access element but I am getting

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements

Please help - Below is the code

```
var highestCleredFormId = dataUpdates.Where(dat => dat.IsCleared).Select(dat => dat.ID).Max();
```

Comment: What is `dataUpdates` ? If this is a list, why is `nhibernate` tagged?

Comment: What value do you want `highestCleredFromId` to have if `dataUpdates` contains no cleared row?

Comment: What is the maximum value in an empty collection? It is not logically possible to answer this question. You have to determine what your code should do when there are no updates which have cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear - in this case `dataUpdates.Where(dat => dat.IsCleared)` has no elements. That is, `dataUpdates` has no elements where the `IsCleared` member has a value of true. Check if there are any elements first, and then get the max:

```cs
var clearedDataUpdates = dataUpdates.Where(dat => dat.IsCleared).ToList();

if (clearedDataUpdates.Any())
{
   var highestClearedFormId = clearedDataUpdates.Select(dat => dat.ID).Max();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: There's `MaxOrDefault` too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe in a third party package like MoreLinq, but it's not built-in as far as I can tell

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos a `MaxOrDefault` style solution is unlikely to be helpful in such a case. It would have to be a sort of sentinel value which, while it could be appropriate for certain kinds of data, it's highly unlikely to be appropriate for things like ID numbers

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when `.Max()` is called on an empty sequence..

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` before `Max`

```
var highestCleredFormId = dataUpdates
                          .Where(dat => dat.IsCleared)
                          .Select(dat => dat.ID)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
                          .Max();
```

Answer (score -2):

This is probably because `dataUpdates.Where(dat => dat.IsCleared)` is empty, please check if any of the object has IsCleared as **true**

You can have null check after Where clause

```
dataUpdates.Where(dat => dat.IsCleared)?.Select(dat => dat.ID).Max();
```

Comment: It's not null, it's empty (`Where()` will never return null). Null and empty are not the same.

Comment: Edited appropriately @Luke

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is still incorrect. Null propagation will not help here because as I said, `Where()` isn't returning null. See the other two answers on this question for valid approaches.